# Quartz scheduler, only certain servers

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

We have a spring configured, clustered quartz scheduler that runs across all of our servers.  Some of these servers are app servers and a few are set aside for running background tasks, mainly pulling jobs from ActiveMQ

The issue we have is there are a few places in code where we inject `Scheduler` to manually schedule jobs at runtime.  We can ensure via a message queue that the only classes doing the manual injection are the background job servers.

All servers run the same code base

How can we configure Quartz so that it only starts the scheduler on the background servers but still ensure that all of the `@Autowire` of `Scheduler` still succeeds

It's setup via

```
<bean id="quartzConfig" class="com.company.quartz.QuartzConfig"/>
```

and

```
@Bean
public JobFactory autowireCapableSpringBeanJobFactory() {
    AutowireCapableSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowireCapableSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setIgnoredUnknownProperties("applicationContext");
    return jobFactory;
}

@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler(@Qualifier("nonXADataSource") DataSource nonXADataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    scheduler.setConfigLocation(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:quartz.properties"));
    scheduler.setSchedulerName("quartzScheduler");
    scheduler.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey("applicationContext");
    scheduler.setNonTransactionalDataSource(nonXADataSource);
    scheduler.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    scheduler.setJobFactory(autowireCapableSpringBeanJobFactory());
    scheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(overwriteExistingJobs);
    scheduler.setAutoStartup(autoStartup);
    scheduler.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown);


    // add a bunch of triggers

    return scheduler;
}
```